# Update table when button is clicked (SQL/JavaScript/HTML)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, sql

When a button is clicked I want "NoOfSpaces" which is a column name in my table to reduce by 1 and "NoOfPeople" to increase by one for a specific event.

For example let's say there is 4 spaces available and 6 people already in the event, when "join" button is clicked, it will then trigger the javascript function 
and the data will change NoOfSpaces to 3 and NoOfPeople to 7.

Table name - soccerearth

Column names- 'NoOfSpaces' and 'NoOfPeople'.

ButtonID (html) - 'btnJoin'.

Datebase - SQLite

Something like below:

```
 tx.executeSql("Update soccerearth SET NoOfSpaces (reduce by 1), NoOfPeople (increase by 1) WHERE ...", successJoin,errorCB);
```

Answer (score 0):

The query should be this  ... (eg: set yourfield = yourfield +1)

```
Update soccerearth SET NoOfSpaces  = NoOfSpaces -1, NoOfPeople  = NoOfPeople +1;
```